similarity from word to sentence after doing words Embedding
I have dataframe with 1000 text rows.
I did word2vec .
Now I want to create a new field which give me the distance from each sentence to the word that i want, lets say the word "king".
I thought about taking in each sentence the 4 closet words to the word king  and make average of them.
maybe by using model.wv.similarity.
the avg of each sentnce will be in the field df['king']
I will glad to know how to do that or to hear about another method.
example data:
    data = {
    'text': [
        "The king sat on the throne with wisdom.",
        "A queen ruled the kingdom alongside the king.",
        "Knights were loyal to their king.",
        "The empire prospered under the rule of a wise monarch."
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['text']=df['text'].str.split()    

model = Word2Vec(df['text'], vector_size=100, window=2, min_count=1 )

model.wv.similarity('Knights','king')

edit:
My mission is:
I have 1000 text rows (people that complain about something)
I want to catalog them into 4 words.
Lets say that word 1 is king. Word 2 is castle…
I want to know about each sentence which word from the  4 words most represent the sentence.
In order to do that I thought about taking each word from the 4 words and calculate model.wv.similarity to all of the words in  df['text'].
After that, for each sentence, take the 3  words that have  the highest score to word king  (and to the word  castle and ets..)  .
calculate mean of the 3 highest score and that would be the value of df['king'] for the sentence

just to make sure; you want to compare sentences with a single word?

IMO it is a problem that is "unsolvable" and I would think in another direction.
Since each sentence contains a lot of "words"; how would determine which word in the sentence should be most important?
Lets take your example of comparing "king" to a sentence "A king is married to a queen. They don't live in a house but a castle".
Which of the words ["king", "queen", "house", "castle"] should produce the highest similarity to your sentence, and why?
If you really should go down that road, then I would suggest a sentence-embedder which you can train to specific tasks i.e you would have a list of sentences and a list of most similar words
texts = ["list of text", "that contains sentences"]
words = ["text", "sentences"]

and then you would train an embedder to produce the highest similarity between each (text[i], words[i]). I doubt it would work that great due, but might do the job.
If you try to describe your "real" problem we might be able to assist your further.

thanks for your answer.  I edit my question
